# Store ajax responses in queue

Tags: jquery

I have created the application in PHP and JQuery of display locations on google map.
 
 
THere are few images in divs after clicking on it there are 3 ajax requests are called in following order 
1: to display video from youtube 
2: to display description from database. 
3: to display locations on map. 
 
After clicking on images in div, result is displayed in following order. 
1: to display description from database. (It is displayed within 1 sec) 
2: to display locations on map.  (It is displayed within 2 sec) 
3: to display video from youtube.  (It is displayed within 2 sec to 3 sec)

As map and youtube video are not located on local server, so that those are taking time to display. 
 
 Is there any way to display all above 3 output when all data will receive from their servers?